# How do I trap a pure virtual method called error?

Tags: c++, gdb

I occasionally get this error

```
pure virtual method called
terminate called without an active exception
```

1. it isn't possible to instantiate an abstract class in C++, so how is it even possible
   to get this situation
2. How can I track this error down ?  The complication here is that one process launches a child process, so it could be in the child or in the parent.

I've added a number of try/catch blocks to the code, but is there some tool that can help trap this error  ?

valgrind is not usable in my situation since this is a high speed encoder with high memory usage, so it takes forever to run.

Any tips or clues would be most welcome.

Comment: typical causes are calling a virtual method in constructor or destructor.

Comment: `struct Base { virtual void naughty() = 0; Base() { naughty(); } }; struct Derived : Base { void naughty() override {} };`  Solution: don't call virtual functions in constructors and destructors — in general.  Especially in the abstract classes themselves.

Comment: Thanks! will a try/catch catch this error ?

Comment: No it will not, it is not allowed by the C++ language specifications.

Comment: Well, the easiest option would be to use a debugger. With gdb (assuming you're not using an ancient version)  you can debug multiple processes at the same time with a single debugger instance. You just need to set [`detach-on-fork`](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb.html/Forks.html#Forks) to `off`, so gdb will attach to both parent and child at the same time.

Comment: If you want all processes to run at the same time (by default gdb will only allow threads of the currently selected process to run) you need to set [`schedule-multiple`](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb.html/All_002dStop-Mode.html#All_002dStop-Mode) to `on`. Then just let it run until the error codition happens, and from there it's debugging as usual. (you can use the [`inferior` command](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb.html/Inferiors-Connections-and-Programs.html#Inferiors-Connections-and-Programs) to switch between the different processes managed by gdb)

Comment: If live debugging is not an option you can setup the system where your program is running so that it captures [core dumps](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/core.5.html) (linux / mac) / [minidumps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dxtecharts/crash-dump-analysis) (windows). core dumps are essentially snapshots of your process at the moment it crashed and can be opened with debuggers (like gdb) to debug crashes long after the process has already exited. (this is called post-mortem debugging)

Comment: On linux you usually only need to make sure you run your program with a non-zero [`RLIMIT_CORE`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html) resource limit  to get core dumps (e.g. with `ulimit -S -c unlimited your-program`). The location where the core dump files are stored is determined by your `kernel.core_pattern` kernel parameter, so you might also want to set that to a suitable path. (see [Enable core dumps](https://linux-audit.com/understand-and-configure-core-dumps-work-on-linux/#enable-core-dumps) for a short crash course)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In GCC/on systems using the Itanium ABI, you can define the function `__cxa_pure_virtual`. This is the function that gets called when a pure virtual function would have gotten invoked that doesn't have another definition.

By default, it just prints "pure virtual method called" then terminates. You can make it throw an exception with a stack trace or have a break point:

```cpp
extern "C" void __cxa_pure_virtual() {
    trap_signal();
    gdb_breakpoint();
    print_stacktrace();
    throw std::runtime_error("pure virtual function called");
}
```

Comment: great! very handy. Turns out the naughty one was not me - exception coming from vendor library

Comment: Note that throwing an exception from `__cxa_pure_virtual` can have a few "fun" side effects on gcc when optimizations are enabled. Depending on what else is on the stack you might experience: destructors not being called during unwinding and / or `catch` blocks being ignored completely, and probably a few other related shenanigans. [godbolt example](https://godbolt.org/z/Mc4cfenqG) - Not that in the first case the destructor for `Foo` was not called when optimizations are enabled, and in the second case the `catch` block was unable to catch the exception at all when optimizations are enabled.

Comment: @Turtlefight is it possible that the call stack I see in `__cxa_pure_virtual` may be incorrect due to a corrupt stack ?

Comment: @Jacko the stack should be fine (assuming it wasn't already corrupted before the pure-virtual call): [godbolt example](https://godbolt.org/z/bW1Ks1r8r). If you compiled with optimizations enabled frames might be missing / slightly off due to inlining, cse, etc... (which should be expected).

Comment: @Jacko What will cause problems is if you're throwing an exception from `__cxa_pure_virtual` and compiling with optimizations enabled. This is due to gcc expecting `__cxa_pure_virtual` to terminate the process (and not throw an exception), so it will not bother generating unwinding code for functions that will call a pure-virtual function. And this can (thanks to inlining) propagate to functions that call that function, etc... Example: [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/zMYqaacrs) - note how `sample()` on the left does not contain any unwinding code for `Foo f`. (the `.cold` section is missing)

Comment: @Turtlefight thanks a lot for the detailed comments. The reason why I ask about corruption is that I opened an issue on vendor site for a bug, as the vendor library is in the stack trace, and someone commented that it might be my code corrupting the stack and causing the pure virtual error. I checked my code and I have no virtual calls in constructor/destructor. So question is: could stack corruption in my code **cause** the pure virtual error with incorrect stack trace pointing to vendor library ?

Comment: @Jacko yes, stack corruption can lead to arbirary functions being listed in the stack trace. However stack corruption is usually easy to spot - most notably by backtraces failing to walk the entire stack, return addresses that point to seemingly nowhere, call, local variables containing unexpected values, functions calling functions that are not present in the source code, etc... If that is the case for your problem in question is impossible to answer without access to at least the stacktrace, and optionally the relevant source code.

Comment: Thanks, good to know.  I ended up finding the root cause, and it's interesting. I had registered callbacks with vendor library, and the callbacks accessed an object whose base had pure virtual methods. Due to race condition, my object was sometimes in the midst of being destroyed when callback executed. Since destructors are called from derived to base, the pure virtual methods were called in this situation. After a lot of debugging, I've fixed the race and no more pure virtual errors !!

Answer (score 5):

A possible cause is that you are calling a virtual member function in a constructor or destructor, where virtual function calls don't work yet.
This is because:

- in a constructor, we haven't constructed the derived class that inherits from us yet
- in a destructor, we have already destroyed the derived class that inherits from us

For example:

```cpp
struct Base {
    Base() { foo(); } // undefined behavior
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

struct Derived : Base {
    void foo() final {}
}
```

##### Tracking down the call

This is normally very easy, because compilers can typically detect this and issue a warning:

```
<source>:2:14: warning: call to pure virtual member function 'foo' has undefined behavior;
                        overrides of 'foo' in subclasses are not available in the
                        constructor of 'Base' [-Wcall-to-pure-virtual-from-ctor-dtor]
    Base() { foo(); }
             ^
```

If this doesn't work for whatever reason, we can track down calls to `Base::foo()`, using a debugger and making it stop when `std::terminate` is called. `break abort` in GDB should work, because `std::terminate` calls `std::abort` by default.

If this isn't possible, we can define a terminate handler using [`std::set_terminate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/set_terminate) and put a breakpoint inside.

If this isn't an available option for whatever reason (e.g. C++98 code base), we can define `Base::foo()` and put a breakpoint inside:

```cpp
void Base::foo() {
    // breakpoint here
}
```